# How do I filter out all vms under a network segment in vcenter using ruby?

Tags: ruby, sdk, vsphere

In the vcenter web console, I can see an overview of all the VMS under various Networks xxx-segment.  How can I filter all the vms under certain network segment using Ruby?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I'm currently using RbVmomi::VIM to get all of the VirtualMachines.  I want to know a way to filter out by network segments instead of listing them all.

Comment: @lacostenycoder, looks like I can do x.network.first.name to get the network segment name. , where `x` is a RbVmomi::VIM::VirtualMachine instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can do x.network.first.name to get the network segment name. , where x is a RbVmomi::VIM::VirtualMachine instance